# Excel VBA Collection Keeps Repeating Last object

Tags: vba, excel

I am having a strange issue trying to populate my object collection. When I am doing the for each loop for `PromptsRange.Rows` everything is perfect.  You can step through the `NewPrompt` area and watch each row pass through and ultimately get added to `PromptsCollection` at the end. The problem I have is after this point.  If you try to do a for each loop on `PromptsCollection`, each object(36) is the exact same and is the last values from the lookuptable. Im stumped. Perhaps one of the scholars can help me out.

Here's my lookuptable
[image]

The following code is inside a userform module.
    Option Explicit

```
Private pPromptsCollection As New Collection
Private pProductPromptMapping As New clsOrderPromptRow
Private pOrderPrompts As New clsOrderPromptRow
Private pTarget As Range
Private pSKU As String

Public Property Get PromptsCollection() As Collection
    Set PromptsCollection = pPromptsCollection
End Property

Public Property Let PromptsCollection(Value As Collection)
    Set pPromptsCollection = Value
End Property

Private Sub SetPromptControls()
Dim PromptsRange As Range
Dim PromptRow As Range

Set PromptsRange = Range("LookUpTablePrompts")

For Each PromptRow In PromptsRange.Rows
    Dim NewPrompt As New clsPrompt
    NewPrompt.Name = PromptRow.Cells(1, 1)
    NewPrompt.ControlType = PromptRow.Cells(1, 2)
    NewPrompt.ComboboxValues = PromptRow.Cells(1, 3)
    NewPrompt.HelpText = PromptRow.Cells(1, 4)
    NewPrompt.TabIndex = PromptRow.Cells(1, 5)
    NewPrompt.ColumnIndex = PromptRow.Cells(1, 6)
    NewPrompt.TableIndex = PromptRow.Cells(1, 7)
    NewPrompt.ControlName = PromptRow.Cells(1, 8)

    PromptsCollection.Add NewPrompt, CStr(NewPrompt.Name)
Next
PromptsCollection.Count
End Sub
```

So now here is where i get the problem. This will result with 36 objects all the same.

```
Dim Prompt As New clsPrompt

For Each Prompt In PromptsCollection
    MsgBox (Prompt.Name)

Next
```

i even pushed it to the watch window to verify all the objects were in face identical. It always results with the last row of the table Bottom Drawer Front Height.

Hope this is clear enough.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using `As New` , VBA will create a new instance of an object the first time it is used.   You should avoid using `As New` and use this pattern instead:

```
Dim NewPrompt As clsPrompt

For Each PromptRow In PromptsRange.Rows
    Set NewPrompt = New clsPrompt
```

Comment: "As New" isn't the real problem. The real problem is that every iteration of the loop is writing to the same object instance. Each iteration needs to create a new object instance as your example code would correctly do. You can still declare the variable "as New" and create a new instance at the start of each loop iteration. But best to do one or the other, so in this case your example code would be my preferred solution.

Comment: @JoeBourne Well said.

Comment: @JoeBourne I saw your comment today, could you explain how you can do this : `You can still declare the variable "as New" and create a new instance at the start of each loop iteration.`? I think that is exactly what the user is doing here : `For Each PromptRow In PromptsRange.Rows
    Dim NewPrompt As New clsPrompt ... Next` but it is not working, because as I assume the *'As New' really is the real problem here*.

Comment: @DanielDušek The issue is that Dimming the object variable inside the loop "as new" doesn't create a new object for each loop as you might expect - it creates one instance and all loop iterations write to the same object instance.
You need to explicitly set the variable to a new instance inside the loop for the code to work. 
its doesnt matter if its dimmed "as new" or not "as new" outside the loop so long as you set the variable to a new instance for each loop iteration.

Comment: @JoeBourne OK now I see what you mean, good point! However, to declare variable As New and then set it explicitly to New instance doesn't make much sense to me because As New enables implicit creation of an object so you don't have to use the Set statement to assign the object reference. But yes, that will help to solve the problem as well.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that its the same instance of the object is being added multiple times to the collection.
Each loop basically updates the values of the same object and thus every element that's already in the collection as they all reference the same object.
At the end all elements in the collection will have the values from the Last Row of data.

As has been said, either explicitly create a new object at the start of each loop

```
For Each PromptRow In PromptsRange.Rows
    Set NewPrompt = New clsPrompt
```

OR  destroy the object once its been added:

```
....
        set NewPrompt = Nothing
    Next
```

Both will ensure a new object is created for each row of your data.

for debug, add these lines to you class:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Debug.Print "Init"
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Debug.Print "Term" & Me.Name
End Sub
```

this will let you see the instances of the objects getting created/terminated in the debug window.

Answer (score 3):

With simple image I would like to explain why the declaration `As New` doesn't work with collection. HTH

[image]