# How do I correctly work with a collection of VBA Class Modules?

Tags: excel, vba, class, collections

I want to create a collection of airports.

An airport has many parameters, but for the sake of simplicity, let's assume an airport class is defined like this in Airport Class Module:

```
'Class Airport
 Public name As String ' Stores name of the airport
 Public flights As Long ' Stores number of flights in that airport
```

Then my module is pretty big but this is the part where I read columns from an Excel file and store values in airports collection, removing duplicate ones:

```
Dim airports As Collection
Set airports = New Collection

'Putting airports in collection
                Dim c As Range
                For Each c In wsToCheck.Range("D:D")
                On Error Resume Next
                Dim airport As New Airport
                airport.name = c.Value
                airports.Add airport, c.Value
                On Error GoTo 0
                Next
```

If I do in the middle

> Debug.Print airport.name

I get the name, but when I do

> Debug.Print airports(1).name

Nothing is printed (but no error neither).

I was using a collection of strings before and it was working. But I need more than one string per airport now.

What is the wrong in my code? Am I using collections right?

Comment: At what point in code did you do the Debug.Print?  When I ran this code, it ran as expected.

Comment: I would also make a class of airports, so you can say `airports.AirPortExists` `getAirportRunways(strAiportCode)` the above code would then exist in the construct, or say `.populateAiports(rng as excel.range)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems with your code.

The first is that are probably creating a `Collection` with millions of items because the range you're iterating over is all of column D (`D:D`). This needs to be bound.

The second issue is your variable name `airport` is the exact same name as your class `Airport`. This can easily confuse VBA, so you need to choose a different name for one of them.

Here's an example that works:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()
    Dim wsToCheck As Worksheet
    Set wsToCheck = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

    Dim airportNames As Range
    Set airportNames = wsToCheck.Range("D1:D10")

    Dim airports As Collection
    Set airports = New Collection

    'Putting airports in collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In airportNames
        Dim thisAirport As Airport
        'Debug.Print c.Address & "=" & c.Value
        Set thisAirport = New Airport
        thisAirport.name = c.Value
        thisAirport.flights = i
        i = i + 1
        airports.Add thisAirport
    Next

    'now print them out
    For i = 1 To airports.Count
        Debug.Print airports(i).name & ", " & airports(i).flights
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: This is working, thank you. However, I don't know the number of airports in each file, 20-30000. I keep doing it with D:D and it doesn't crash. May it lead to some problems?

Comment: As a general rule, you should use the VBA to determine how many airports you have in that column. You'll need to figure out what the last row number is to set your range, for example: `Dim lastRow as Long`, `lastRow = wsToCheck.Range("A" & wsToCheck.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Doing that has improved the speed of my program really a lot. From 2 minutes to 20 seconds more or less. Great advice.

Answer (score 3):

Besides the problems @PeterT has mentioned the biggest problem in your code is the way the new `Airport` objects are created. I should better say `Airport` object, because there are actually no objects but just one object.

This is caused by the way the airport variable is declared: `Dim airport As New Airport`. In [VBA-Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/dim-statement) to `Dim` statement we can find the reason why only one object is created here:

> New keyword enables implicit creation of an object. If you use New
>   when declaring the object variable, a new instance of the object is
>   created on first reference to it, so you don't have to use the Set
>   statement to assign the object reference.

So `Dim New` ensures, new instance is created when the variable `airport` is used for the first time. But thats it. No other instances are created, just this first one. In each loop just this one instance is changed and added to the collection. So your collection contains references to the same airport object.

But you need all the airport object, not just the one. So the `New` must be used with `Set`. The Documentation says:

> When New is used with Set, it creates a new instance of the class

---

Consider the following code *(Range D1:D3 contains values AAAA, BBBB, CCCC)*

```
Dim airports As Collection
Set airports = New Collection
Dim c As Range

For Each c In Worksheets(1).Range("D1:D3")
    Dim Airport As New Airport
    Airport.name = c.Value
    airports.Add Airport
Next

Dim airports2 As Collection
Set airports2 = New Collection
Dim airport2 As Airport
For Each c In Worksheets(1).Range("D1:D3")
    Set airport2 = New Airport
    airport2.name = c.Value
    airports2.Add airport2
Next

Debug.Print "Airports:"
For Each airport2 In airports
    Debug.Print airport2.name
Next

Debug.Print vbNewLine

Debug.Print "Airports2:"
For Each airport2 In airports2
    Debug.Print airport2.name
Next
```

> Output

```
Airports:
CCCC
CCCC
CCCC


Airports2:
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
```

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39339741/excel-vba-collection-keeps-repeating-last-object/39343719#39343719) is about the same problem.