# I can't get an addition to the workbook class to instance more than once

Tags: excel, vba, class

I've got a user form with a set of dynamic buttons that each open a workbook to allow the user to perform a copy and paste data entry process.

To hopefully avoid the workbooks being closed I've added a message to the `BeforeClose` code of these workbooks via a class like so:

```
'normal module
Public tempDataWB As New wbClass

'class module - wbClass
Public WithEvents dataWB As Workbook

Private Sub dataWB_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    
    MsgBox "Don't close me!"
    
End Sub
```

The button code is as follows:

```
'normal module
Public teamOpen(0 to teamSize) As New teamOpens

Sub loadteams
    
    For each team in teamList   
        Set cntrl = addNewButton(team.Name)   
        Set teamOpen(x).teamOpenButton = cntrl
        x = x + 1
    Next team

End Sub

'class module - teamOpens
Public WithEvents teamOpenButton As MSForms.CommandButton

Private Sub teamOpenButton_Click()

    Set tempDataWB.dataWB = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    
End Sub
```

If I directly add buttons in design time with the `Workbooks.Add` line in them then it works for multiple buttons but when it's in a class module for buttons added during runtime it only works on the first button clicked.

I'm really not sure what I'm missing and a pointer in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Note: I've simplified the code down to the bare bones to try and highlight the problem I'm having.

Comment: Isn't the line `teamOpen(x).teamOpenButton = cntrl` missing a `Set`? And in general avoid the `As New`.

Comment: So it is, I'll amend, it doesn't in my actual code. Why should the New be avoided?

Comment: Why `As New` could be source of the problems read e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44734087/863240).

Comment: I applied your suggestion but it made no difference. I removed the `New` from the `Dim` and added this line: `Set tempDataWB = New wbClass`

Comment: Hah, I must have been not with it on Friday lol, I found the issue with a boolean value not being reset, lessen learnt, I should have done what I just did and that was to reproduce the error in a new project setting like I just did. Thanks for the help @DanielDušek